# GD Image library: Range of colour component arguments for TrueColor images

Tags: c++, api, graphics, gd

I'm trying to output a TrueColor image using GD (specifically bgd.dll) from a C++ program under windows. The [API](http://libgd.org/Colour) (or at least the examples) seem to suggest that the range of the integer RGB arguments for gdResolveColor spans the values 0-255. Is this correct?

I've experimented with higher values and gotten strange results but this could well be to due my own lack of understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. True color uses one byte for each color component (red, green and blue). The range of an byte is 0 to 255, hence the range indicated in the GD documentation. So, 16,777,216  (2^24 or 256^3) different colors can be specified using these 3 bytes (24-bits).

I'm not sure how GD handles invalid inputs (i.e. a color component over 255). It likely masks the input and you end up with the your submitted value modulo 255.

Comment: This was me getting my permutations and combinations mixed up.